# Google gRPC (C++) building under VisualStudio 2013. Link errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, grpc

I'm trying to setup gRPC for my project in Visual Studio. Did everything as described here: http://www.infopulse.com/blog/grpc-framework-by-google-tutorial/. (Trying to compile helloworld example -> Git grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld)

#### The main problem I'm getting, while compiling:

> unresolved external symbol "void _cdecl grcp::FillMetadata
>   *... and so on.*

Nothing wrong with protobuf (Everything working)
OpenSSL, zlib - OK.

#### My Includes:

- $(SolutionDir)..
- $(SolutionDir)..\include
- $(SolutionDir)..\third_party\protobuf\src
- $(SolutionDir)\packages\grpc.dependencies.zlib.1.2.8.10\build\native\include
- $(SolutionDir)\packages\grpc.dependencies.openssl.1.0.204.1\build\native\include
- $(SolutionDir)\packages\gflags.2.1.2.1\build\native\include
- $(SolutionDir)\packages\gtest.1.7.0.1\build\native\include

#### Additional dependencies:

- libprotobuf.lib
- grpc.lib
- gpr.lib
- libeay32MDd.lib
- ssleay32MDd.lib

Everything in correct folders.

What am I missing here? Maybe some of you have an already working `.sln` project with all dependencies list? I know that the problem must be connected to some `.lib` that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not linking in the grpc++ code. It's unfortunately not a supported target right now, but we're looking to remedy that very soon. I'd really like to be offering a nuget package for C++ users.

If you want to try for now though, make sure you're compiling the vsprojects/vcxproj/grpc++/grpc++.vcxproj project alongside the rest of your code. Let us know how you go (and please file bugs at github.com/grpc/grpc/issues to help us prioritize things).

Comment: Thank you for your help) The following link describes the right changes in Project Properties I've done - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4707